# Mac OS X Unix to find replace using regular expression

Tags: macos, unix

this is my first question so apologies if this has been answered before. I have searched but cannot find what I am looking for.

I have a huge amount of text that has been exported from a database. For certain attribute content, I need to find each instance of a space followed by a capital letter and just replace the space with a semi-colon(;).

For example:

```
First one Second one Third one Fourth one
```

Should become:

```
First one;Second one;Third one;Fourth one
```

Using Unix (Mac OS X) The following just returns the whole line:

```
echo "First one Second one Third one Fourth one" | grep ' [A-Z]'
```

How would I achieve my desired outcome please? Any help or pointers would be very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sed` for such task:

```
$ echo "First one Second one Third one Fourth one" | sed -Ee 's/ ([A-Z])/;\1/g'
First one;Second one;Third one;Fourth one
```

- `-E` option is specified to use extended regular expression.

---

- `s/pattern/replace-string/g` finds pattern and replace with the *replace-string*  **g**lobally.
- `[A-Z]` matches uppercase alphabet. by surrounding the pattern with `(..)`, it can be referenced later in replace-string.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for a very swift response. I had a stab at awk and tr but not sed!

Comment: Sorry, just spotted... what does the "1" do?

Comment: `\1` back-reference the first group ( the part of pattern surrounded by `(...)`)